# How to mount a sambashare with autofs and cifs

Tags: mount, samba, automount, cifs, autofs

I'm trying to automount a sambashare as CIFS, as documented here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs#CIFS

This seems so simple, I'm running out of things to google. It's probably something very obvious. Let me speak in commands:

`sudo apt-get install autofs`

`sudo nano /etc/auto.master.d/myserver.autofs`

```
files -fstype=cifs,rw ://server/files
```

`sudo automount -f -v`

```
Starting automounter version 5.0.7, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.02
syntax error in map near [ files -fstype=cifs,rw : ]
no mounts in table
```

I didn't do a whole lot, but I still did something wrong. How do I get this working?

---

*edit* @Jos

updated `myserver.autofs`:

```
/media/server/files -fstype=cifs,rw ://server/files
```

Output from `sudo automount -f -v`:

```
Starting automounter version 5.0.7, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.02
:
/
/
/
file map /etc/-fstype=cifs not found
mounted indirect on /media/server/files with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
statemachine:1363: got unexpected signal 28!
```

Now we have a directory in `/media`! But it's empty.

Comment: Perhaps the mount point needs to contain the full path? (i.e. `/path/to/files -fstype=cifs,rw ://server/files`)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen such as? `auto.master` contains `+dir:/etc/auto.master.d` which is empty.

Comment: @Jos ok that seems to help, but I think the line is different from what was expected. It searches for the `-fstype` flag as if it's searching for a binary. I think the docs are outdated.

Comment: Hm. According to the most recent [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/autofs) it should be correct as stated.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting a direct map line in "/etc/auto.master" - something like:

```
/-  /etc/auto.data
```

Where "/etc/auto.data" contains the "direct" mount point and your cifs mount info that you previously had in "myserver.autofs" - i.e.:

```
/media/server/files -fstype=cifs,rw ://server/files
```

I am new to autofs and was not able to get an "indirect" mapping working for a cifs mount but the above "direct" mapping method works for me.

Comment: Until reading your post I didn't notice that direct and indirect mappings were different! Now I've got something working.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem until I figured out reading a lot of pages. Try this:

1. Make a sub-directory for automount in `/media` like `/media/auto` (I wanted to automount two different servers/files here and `/media` is available for other stuffs)
2. Edit `/etc/auto.master` with:

   ```
   /media/auto /etc/auto.cifs-shares --timeout=500
   ```

   (You can give another name to file "auto.cifs-shares" and change timeout to another value if you want to)
3. Create a file for store your config (as I wrote above I've written in `/etc/auto.cifs-shares`)

   ```
   files --fstype=cifs,credentials=/home/your_user/.credentials,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=your_user,rw ://server/files
   ```

   (if you don't give credentials it will automount as anonymous, it depends on permission)
4. You have to restart service for having changes taking effect:

   ```
   service autofs restart
   ```
5. That's it! Next try:

   ```
   ls /media/auto/files
   ```

(should give you what you want)

Comment: Should that be `-fstype` instead of `--fstype`?